# How Do I Programmatically Use "Count" In Pyspark?

Tags: sql, apache-spark, pyspark, count, apache-spark-sql

Trying to do a simple count in Pyspark programmatically but coming up with errors.  `.count()` works at the end of the statement if I drop `AS (count(city))` but I need the count to appear inside not on the outside.

```
result = spark.sql("SELECT city AS (count(city)) AND business_id FROM business WHERE city = 'Reading'")
```

One of many errors

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o24.sql.
: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException: 
mismatched input '(' expecting ')'(line 1, pos 21)

== SQL ==
SELECT city AS (count(city)) AND business_id FROM business WHERE city = 'Reading'
---------------------^^^
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is incorrect. Maybe you want to do this instead:

```
result = spark.sql("""
    SELECT 
        count(city) over(partition by city), 
        business_id 
    FROM business 
    WHERE city = 'Reading'
""")
```

You need to provide a window if you use `count` without `group by`. In this case, you probably want a count for each city.

Comment: Boss this solution doesn't work for me but its where I need to be with the code I need to write.  it is giving me the count in one column and all business ids in the other.  I'm going to add my solution below but if I can get this to work kudos to you.  And Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Just my solution to the problem I'm trying to solve.  The solution above is where I would like to be at.

```
result = spark.sql("SELECT count(*) FROM business WHERE city='Reading'")
```